# Select count group by another count (My)SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, group-by

Let's say I have a table that lists cars by user.

```
id | user_id | color
 1 |       1 |   red
 2 |       1 |   red
 3 |       2 |  blue
 4 |       2 |   red
 5 |       3 |   red
```

Now, I want to know how much red cars each client has, so I've done this SQL :

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(color)
FROM cars
WHERE color = 'red'
GROUP BY user_id
```

Which lists me :

```
1 | 2
2 | 1
3 | 1
```

But what I really want is the count of each count. Something like :

```
Users with 1 red car : 2
Users with 2 red car : 1
...
```

So is there a way to count my select which already includes a count() grouped by ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an aggregation of aggregations:

```
SELECT redCount, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT user_id, COUNT(color) as redCount
      FROM cars
      WHERE color = 'red'
      GROUP BY user_id
     ) uc
GROUP BY redCount;
```

Comment: Wow, didn't know it was possible, I actually tried something like that, but I got errors because I didn't add an alias to the SELECT table. Thank you it worked !